# Update com duas tabelas ao mesmo tempo

Tags: php, sql, banco-de-dados, sql-update

Estou fazendo um update para janela de edição e não está dando erro, mas está funcionando somente a parte de endereço, a parte das informações do apicultor não está atualizando

[image: Tabela endereço][Tabela apicultor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4092.jpg)

```php
<?php 
session_start();
require_once "conexao.php";


$nome_apicultor = $_POST['nome_apicultor'];
$sobrenome_apicultor = $_POST['sobrenome_apicultor'];
$email_apicultor = $_POST['email_apicultor'];
$cpf_apicultor = $_POST['cpf_apicultor'];
$rua_apicultor = $_POST['rua_apicultor'];
$numero_apicultor = $_POST['numero_apicultor'];
$bairro_apicultor = $_POST['bairro_apicultor'];
$cidade_apicultor = $_POST['cidade_apicultor'];
$complemento_apicultor = $_POST['complemento_apicultor'];
$telefone_apicultor = $_POST['telefone_apicultor'];
$estado_apicultor = $_POST['estado_apicultor'];
$codEndereco = $_POST['codEndereco'];
$codApicultor = $_SESSION["token"];

try {
    $prepared = $conexao_pdo->prepare("UPDATE `endereco` SET `endereco` = :rua_apicultor, `bairro` = :bairro_apicultor, `numero` = :numero_apicultor, `complemento` = :complemento_apicultor, `cidade` = :cidade_apicultor, `estado` = :estado_apicultor  where `cod` = :codEndereco;");
    $prepared->bindParam(":rua_apicultor", $rua_apicultor);
    $prepared->bindParam(":bairro_apicultor", $bairro_apicultor);
    $prepared->bindParam(":numero_apicultor", $numero_apicultor);
    $prepared->bindParam(":complemento_apicultor", $complemento_apicultor);
    $prepared->bindParam(":cidade_apicultor", $cidade_apicultor);
    $prepared->bindParam(":estado_apicultor", $estado_apicultor);
    $prepared->bindParam(":codEndereco", $codEndereco);
    $prepared->execute();
    $id_end = $conexao_pdo->lastInsertId();

    if($prepared->rowCount() > 0) {
        $prepared = $conexao_pdo->prepare("UPDATE `apicultor` SET `nome` = :nome_apicultor, `sobrenome` = :sobrenome_apicultor, `email` = :email_apicultor, `cpf` = :cpf_apicultor, `telefone` = :telefone_apicultor, `endereco_cod` = :endereco_cod  where `cod` = :codApicultor;");
        $prepared->bindParam(":nome_apicultor", $nome_apicultor);
        $prepared->bindParam(":sobrenome_apicultor", $sobrenome_apicultor);
        $prepared->bindParam(":email_apicultor", $email_apicultor);
        $prepared->bindParam(":cpf_apicultor", $cpf_apicultor);
        $prepared->bindParam(":telefone_apicultor", $telefone_apicultor);
        $prepared->bindParam(":codApicultor", $codApicultor);
        $prepared->bindParam(":endereco_cod", $id_end);
        $prepared->execute();

        if($prepared->rowCount() > 0) {
            header("Location: ../Perfil.php");
        }
        else {
            header("Location: ../Perfil.php");
        }
    }
    else {
        header("Location: ../Perfil.php");
    }

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    print $e->getMessages();
    die();
}
?>
```

Comment: Defina uma transação com os dois comandos UPDATE, um para cada tabela, que eles serão executados de forma atômica, isto é, ou os dois UPDATES serão executados ou nenhum deles será.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para podermos ajudar melhor coloque essas duas tabelas do seu banco de dados na pergunta. E se o `endereco_cod` que você passou for chave primária coloque ele na cláusula where em vez de editá-lo. Algo assim:

```
UPDATE `apicultor` SET `nome` = :nome_apicultor, `sobrenome` = :sobrenome_apicultor, `email` = :email_apicultor, `cpf` = :cpf_apicultor, `telefone` = :telefone_apicultor  
where `endereco_cod` = :endereco_cod and `cod_Apicultor` = :codApicultor;
```

E algo que eu notei também é que na sua claúsula `where` nos dois updates está escrito `cod = :codEndereco;` e no outro `cod = :codEndereco;`, o `cod` então seria o mesmo em endereço e apicultor?

Comment: Coloquei as duas tabelas na pergunta

Comment: Se você estiver usando POO da uma olhada na documentação para deixa-la mais simples que você irá entender melhor: https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.pdo.php  Por que do jeito que você colocou o código eu não sei se você pode usar funções que era o que eu recomendaria. Proucura algo melhor sobre o padrão MVC se você não entender.